# In Grails (GORM), how to override a constraint name

Tags: grails-orm

In **Grails (GORM)**, how to override a constraint name (in the generated dbm script). I am using Oracle with GORM.
It seems the length of the constraint name is restricted to 15.

If there's no way to override then is there a way to alter the length to more than 15 (say 25)!!

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE X ( 
       id NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL, 
       CONSTRAINT overridden_name_here 
       PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of your domain class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if the latest Grails 3 provides a more direct way of customizing the constraint names, but in Grails 2.4.5 and earlier versions the way to go is with a custom configuration subclass.

It essentially involves creating your own configuration by extending **GrailsAnnotationConfiguration** and overriding the *secondPassCompile()* method. In this method you can access your domain class and access/set many different properties including something like the foreign key constraint name.

For a detailed example please see Burt Beckwith's post: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=465

I believe the length limit of the name for a constraint is determined by the underlying database implementation and not GORM itself.

Comment: All examples are suited for foreign keys. What about customizing the primary key name? Or in general, a constraint name?

Comment: I've only specified custom FK names in the past, but according to this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289126/how-to-choose-ddl-primary-key-constraint-names-with-jpa-hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289126/how-to-choose-ddl-primary-key-constraint-names-with-jpa-hibernate), Hibernate doesn't support it. There is a ticket for it on Hibernate: [https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HB-1245](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HB-1245)

Answer (score 4):

In Grails 3, if you are using Hibernate 4.x you just need extend the class **HibernateMappingContextConfiguration** and override the *secondPassCompile* method to customize the foreign key names. However if you want use Hibernate 5, the solution is slightly different. See  the graeme's comment on the slack grails-community:

> Not our fault. Hibernate 5 is significantly different so we had to adapt. They essentially deprecated the Configuration hierarchy as well as changed how you hook into metadata. For Hibernate 5.2 this is going to have to change again.

So, to solve this problem related to Hibernate 5 and Grails 3, I did the implementation below. First we need to override the default hibernate implementation:

```
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitForeignKeyNameSource;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl;

public class ReadableImplicitNamingStrategy extends ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl {

    public static final ReadableImplicitNamingStrategy INSTANCE = new ReadableImplicitNamingStrategy();

    private String getPlural(String tableName) {

        final int len = tableName.length();
        final boolean isLower = Character.isLowerCase(tableName.charAt(len - 1));
        final String s = tableName.toLowerCase();
        final char lastChar = s.charAt(len - 1);

        String result = tableName;

        switch (lastChar) {
            case 'y':
                result = tableName.substring(0, tableName.length() -1) + (isLower? "ie": "IE"); break;
            case 's':
            case 'x':
            case 'z':
                result = tableName.substring(0, tableName.length() -1) + (isLower? "e": "E"); break;
            default:
                if (s.endsWith("sh")) {
                    result = tableName.substring(0, tableName.length() -1) + (isLower? "e": "E");
                }
        }
        result += (isLower? "s": "S");
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier determineForeignKeyName(ImplicitForeignKeyNameSource source) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("FK_")
                .append(source.getReferencedTableName().getText())
                .append("_")
                .append(getPlural(source.getTableName().getText()));

        return toIdentifier(sb.toString(), source.getBuildingContext());

    }
}
```

Also, we have to create a class to customize the Gorm Configuration:

```
import org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration

    class GormConfiguration extends HibernateMappingContextConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected void reset() {
            super.reset();
            this.implicitNamingStrategy = ReadableImplicitNamingStrategy.INSTANCE;
        }

    }
```

And finally, refer in our application.yml the customized class we are going to use in our DataSource.

```
dataSource:
    dbCreate: update
    configClass: mypackage.GormConfiguration
```

Comment: Hey Wellington I am upgrading to grails 3.2.3 thanks for your answer it seems promising but I cannot get the following import statements import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitForeignKeyNameSource;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl; and I have the following in my gradle classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.4"  as well as  compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.2.Final"compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.2.Final".

Comment: You are using the plugin version 6.0.6, I used the version 5.0.1 of hibernate. You can change your file `build.gradle` but I don't know the effects.
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:5.0.1"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.0.Final"

Comment: By the way, did not have a chance to try the Grails latest version, I'm still using the 3.0.2. I had some issues with the fields plugin trying to upgrade and because I did not have enough time I got stick with this version.