# Define PK_name via JPA annotation

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using spring boot with SQL server and I want to define the PK_name from spring rather than let it generated automatically.

Hibernate is adding a suffix number to the primary key.

So instead of **PK__Team__3214EC07FA39AD63**  I would like to give this name **PK_Team**

```
 @Entity
public class Team {
  @Id
@Column(name = "Id" )
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "FirstName")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "FamilyName")
private String familyName;
@Column(name = "Email")
private String email;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: I don't think Hibernate allows you to name primary keys the way you want. Check this little old post but seems still useful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289126/how-to-choose-ddl-primary-key-constraint-names-with-jpa-hibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to specify the name however I think it is probably possible to prevent the suffix universally via a custom dialect which overrides the

`org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect#getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName)`

method.

You cannot do anything about the name passed in however you can substring it to remove the suffix.

```
public class MyCustomSqlServerDialect extend SqlServer2012Dialect{

    @Override
    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        // default implementation
        // return " add constraint " + constraintName + " primary key ";

        return " add constraint " + 
                    constraintName.subString(0, constraintName.lastIndexOf("__")) +
                        " primary key "   
    }
}
```

Then obviously just set this dialect in the relevant Spring/Hibernate property.

Comment: Thank you Alan .

Comment: Are you sure getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString could override ?

Comment: It's a public method. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString-java.lang.String-

Comment: Unfortunately the schema export classes don't make use of that method to create the primary key. You should override also the StandardTableExporter (and Dialect.getTableExporter to return your table exporter)